# How to use alanning roles in Meteor react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I am trying to build simple user authentication system in meteor react js but I am not able to add roles to created user I don't know what is going wrong in my project https://github.com/robertjchow/cv

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Searching your repository for `Roles.` calls reveals, that only your **client** code is adding users to roles.

Now let's think a minute about the fact that client code can be manipulated.

Do you think that this is still a valid authentication, when clients can add users to roles?

Now going a step further and checking the documentation of the package at: https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles reveals, that the documentation is adding roles only at the server side, while on the client side it only allows reading via `isInRole`.

Therefore your next steps should be to create new users only on the server with methods and also add the Roles also only there.

**Update:** To create new users on your server, you need to add the `accounts-password` package (but keep the `accounts-base` package). Otherwise there would be no `Accounts.createUser` function available.

Further reading: https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html

Comment: Thanks I got it working by using meteor call method from client and adding roles on server but I don't know how to create new user on server as when I called Accounts.createUser function on server from client I got error that createUser function cannot be executed on server yet.

Comment: Will look into that in this eveneing

Comment: Updated my answer.